# sql file of PhyMyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have created a database and table using phpMyAdmin. I want to submit sql file that contains my database and table to someone. How can I access phpMyadmin's sql file? I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't really know phpmyadmin, but doesn't it have an Export function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First open your phpmyadmin and then click on your database name then click on export option menu and finally click on Go button to download your sql file. Now you got the sql file of your database and tables.

Answer (score 2):

in `phpmyadmin` `select` our `database` now you should see `export` option` appear on the top.

then select `Custom - display all possible options` and click go the sql file should b created in your download folder